# When to use a full bleed button and when not to?

Tags: usability, buttons, material-design

I have attached a screen shot of a design that I am working on. I am not able to decide if the bottom button should be full bleed or if the present version is good enough. Can someone please tell me why once I should go for and why?

[image]

Any suggestions with valid reasons are also welcome

Comment: I think any answer would be mostly a matter of opinion and based on the specifics and context of your implementation.

Answer (score 4):

### I would advice against using a full bleed button

Here's why:

- **Snackbar** - In android, the snackbar takes up the bottom-most region of the screen to show notifications and pop-up info. A full-bleed would look like that and might confuse the users

[image: Android snackbar]

- **Usability** - On a handheld device, the bottom area is hard to reach and if you research on most-used UI's you will find out that primary CTA and buttons are usually placed with some padding at the bottom to make them more accessible

[image: Bottom-aligned button with padding]

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. Will wait for some more answers or reasons